# Binary Formatter Saving Loading But Not Buying

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binary, formatter

I am using Binary Formatter for saving the data for game variables. It is saving highscore, coins and loading very well. But when player has 10 coins, I want him to be able to buy some item. It is working on editor perfect. But in android device, it is not working. But again, it is saving and loading coins and highscore. Here is my code:

GameController Class

```
[SerializeField]
private Text coinText,highScoreText;

public static GameController instance;
public GameData data;
public int currentLevel;
public int currentScore;

public bool isGameStartedFirstTime;
public bool isMusicOn;
public int selectedLevel;
public int coins;
public int highScore;
public bool[] levels;

void Awake () 
{
    MakeSingleton();
    InitializeGameVariables();
    coinText.text=data.getCoins().ToString ();
    highScoreText.text = data.getHighScore().ToString ();
}

void MakeSingleton()
{
    if(instance!=null)
        Destroy (gameObject);
    else
    {
        instance=this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
void InitializeGameVariables()
{
    Load ();
    if(data!=null)
    {
        isGameStartedFirstTime=data.getIsGameStartedFirstTime();
    }
    else
    {
        isGameStartedFirstTime=true;
    }
    if(isGameStartedFirstTime)
    {
        highScore=0;
        coins=0;
        selectedLevel=0;
        isGameStartedFirstTime=false;
        isMusicOn=false;
        levels = new bool[7];

        levels[0] = true;
        for(int i = 1; i<levels.Length;i++)
        {
            levels[i] = false;
        }

        data = new GameData();
        data.setHighScore(highScore);
        data.setCoins(coins);
        data.setIsGameStartedFirstTime(isGameStartedFirstTime);
        data.setLevels(levels);
        data.setMusicOn(isMusicOn);
        data.setSelectedLevel(selectedLevel);

        Save ();
        Load ();
    }
    else
    {
        highScore=data.getHighScore();
        coins = data.getCoins();
        isGameStartedFirstTime = data.getIsGameStartedFirstTime();
        levels=data.getLevels();
        isMusicOn=data.getMusicOn();
        selectedLevel=data.getSelectedLevel();
    }
}
public void  Save()
{
    FileStream file = null;
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameData.dat");
        if(data!=null)
        {
            data.setHighScore(highScore);
            data.setCoins(coins);
            data.setIsGameStartedFirstTime(isGameStartedFirstTime);
            data.setLevels(levels);
            data.setMusicOn(isMusicOn);
            data.setSelectedLevel(selectedLevel);

            bf.Serialize(file,data);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if(file!=null)
        file.Close();
    }
}
public void Load()
{
    FileStream file = null;

    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameData.dat",FileMode.Open);
        data = (GameData)bf.Deserialize(file);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if(file!=null)
            file.Close();
    }
}
```

GameData Class

```
private bool isGameStartedFirstTime;
private bool isMusicOn;
private int selectedLevel;
private int coins;
private int highScore;
private bool[] levels;

public void setIsGameStartedFirstTime(bool isGameStartedFirstTime)
{
    this.isGameStartedFirstTime = isGameStartedFirstTime;
}
public bool getIsGameStartedFirstTime()
{
    return this.isGameStartedFirstTime;
}
public void setMusicOn(bool isMusicOn)
{
    this.isMusicOn=isMusicOn;
}
public bool getMusicOn()
{
    return this.isMusicOn;
}
public void setSelectedLevel(int selectedLevel)
{
    this.selectedLevel=selectedLevel;
}
public int getSelectedLevel()
{
    return this.selectedLevel;
}
public void setCoins(int coins)
{
    this.coins=coins;
}
public int getCoins()
{
    return this.coins;
}
public void setHighScore(int highScore)
{
    this.highScore=highScore;
}
public int getHighScore()
{
    return this.highScore;
}
public void setLevels(bool[] levels)
{
    this.levels=levels;
}
public bool[] getLevels()
{
    return this.levels;
}
```

And here is my buying code :

```
public void BuyItem(int index)
{
    if(GameController.instance.levels[index]==true)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel ("Zombies");
    }
    else
    {
        if(GameController.instance.coins>=10)
        {
            BuyImages[index-1].SetActive (false);
            GameController.instance.levels[index]=true;
            GameController.instance.coins-=10;
            coinsText.text="" + GameController.instance.coins;
            GameController.instance.Save ();

        }
    }

}
```

It is working on editor but not device although saving the data works.

Comment: Please only post code which is directly relevant to your problem/question

Comment: These codes are relevant already. One of them for saving data, other one is for buying.

Comment: One more think, I guess isGameStartedFirstTime variable in the InitializeGameVariables method  never coming true. Because when I change the coins variable to some other number, it stays still 0. But if change isGameStartedFirstTime with true it is working. But of course then app thinks at every time it is first time so resetes the variables.

Comment: What error are you experiencing? Please be more specific. You haven't really asked a question yet.

Comment: I've solved it. What I was asking is why buy button not doing its job although the data variables loading perfectly. I just changed public GameData data to private. I dont know how that solved the problem but anyway, thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.